Ardour 8 crashes in ubuntu studio 24.04
I did a fresh install of Ubuntu Studio 24.04 lts, packed with pipewire and pipewire-jack by default. All sound works great, except Ardour 8.4.
Ardour runs, but when I click play, the sound is noisy with random velocity variations.
I used the same laptop to run Ubuntu Studio 22.04 lts and there wasn´t any trouble. In the old 22.04 I used the same config (48000HZ,512,2 periods) for jack and didn't get any XRUN or Ardour crashes.  It was a happy life recording beautiful songs.
I tried to disable pipewire option to run only jack, but got the same noise. Could pipewire-jack or jack have some kind of fail or misconfiguration in 24.04?
While running Ardour in Ubuntu studio 24.04 (without playing or recording), I get these journal log messages:
may 24 10:54:07 HarleyQuinn pipewire[1880]: spa.alsa: hw:sofhdadspp: follower avail:92 delay:92 target:512 thr:512, resync (4 suppressed)
may 24 10:54:09 HarleyQuinn pipewire[1880]: spa.alsa: hw:sofhdadspp: follower avail:64 delay:64 target:512 thr:512, resync (4 suppressed)
may 24 10:54:30 HarleyQuinn pipewire[1880]: spa.alsa: hw:sofhdadspp: follower avail:14 delay:14 target:512 thr:512, resync (4 suppressed)
may 24 10:54:32 HarleyQuinn pipewire[1880]: spa.alsa: hw:sofhdadspp: follower avail:101 delay:101 target:512 thr:512, resync (5 suppressed)
may 24 10:54:34 HarleyQuinn pipewire[1880]: spa.alsa: hw:sofhdadspp: follower avail:55 delay:55 target:512 thr:512, resync (4 suppressed)
may 24 10:54:36 HarleyQuinn pipewire[1880]: spa.alsa: hw:sofhdadspp: follower avail:82 delay:82 target:512 thr:512, resync (4 suppressed)
may 24 10:54:38 HarleyQuinn pipewire[1880]: spa.alsa: hw:sofhdadspp: follower avail:11 delay:11 target:512 thr:512, resync (3 suppressed)
may 24 10:54:40 HarleyQuinn pipewire[1880]: spa.alsa: hw:sofhdadspp: follower avail:31 delay:31 target:512 thr:512, resync (6 suppressed)
may 24 10:54:42 HarleyQuinn pipewire[1880]: spa.alsa: hw:sofhdadspp: follower avail:11 delay:11 target:512 thr:512, resync (6 suppressed)
may 24 10:54:44 HarleyQuinn pipewire[1880]: spa.alsa: hw:sofhdadspp: follower avail:101 delay:101 target:512 thr:512, resync (4 suppressed)
may 24 10:54:46 HarleyQuinn pipewire[1880]: spa.alsa: hw:sofhdadspp: follower avail:101 delay:101 target:512 thr:512, resync (5 suppressed)

My sound devices:
root@HarleyQuinn:/home/alex# aplay -l
**** Lista de PLAYBACK dispositivos hardware ****
tarjeta 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], dispositivo 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdispositivos: 0/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], dispositivo 3: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], dispositivo 4: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], dispositivo 5: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], dispositivo 31: HDA Analog Deep Buffer (*) []
  Subdispositivos: 1/1

root@HarleyQuinn:/home/alex# arecord -l
**** Lista de CAPTURE dispositivos hardware ****
tarjeta 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], dispositivo 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdispositivos: 0/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], dispositivo 6: DMIC (*) []
  Subdispositivos: 0/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], dispositivo 7: DMIC16kHz (*) []
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
root@HarleyQuinn:/home/alex# lshw -C sound
  *-usb:1                   
       descripción: Vídeo
       producto: HP TrueVision HD Camera
       fabricante: DMWCR0A9IGBF8T
       id físico: 3
       información del bus: usb@1:3
       versión: 0.03
       serie: 0001
       capacidades: usb-2.01
       configuración: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       descripción: Multimedia audio controller
       producto: Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       id físico: 1f.3
       información del bus: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       nombre lógico: card0
       nombre lógico: /dev/snd/controlC0
       nombre lógico: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
       nombre lógico: /dev/snd/hwC0D2
       nombre lógico: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
       nombre lógico: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
       nombre lógico: /dev/snd/pcmC0D31p
       nombre lógico: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
       nombre lógico: /dev/snd/pcmC0D4p
       nombre lógico: /dev/snd/pcmC0D5p
       nombre lógico: /dev/snd/pcmC0D6c
       nombre lógico: /dev/snd/pcmC0D7c
       versión: 01
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuración: driver=sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl latency=32
       recursos: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:149 memoria:6002130000-6002133fff memoria:6002000000-60020fffff


root@HarleyQuinn:/home/alex# inxi -Aa
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    alternate: snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl bus-ID: 00:1f.3
    chip-ID: 8086:51c8 class-ID: 0401
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-31-lowlatency status: kernel-api with: osspd
    status: active tools: alsactl,alsamixer,amixer
  Server-1: JACK v: 1.9.21 status: n/a (root, process) with: a2jmidid
    status: off tools: jack_control,jack_mixer,qjackctl
  Server-2: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: n/a (root, process) with:
    1: pipewire-pulse status: active 2: wireplumber status: active
    3: pipewire-alsa type: plugin 4: pw-jack type: plugin
    tools: pactl,pw-cat,pw-cli,wpctl



root@HarleyQuinn:/home/alex# lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 149, IOMMU group 9
        Memory at 6002130000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Memory at 6002000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
        Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller
        Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 9
        Memory at 6002138000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
root@HarleyQuinn:/home/alex# 

pipewire/noble,now 1.0.5-1 amd64 [instalado]
  audio and video processing engine multimedia server

pipewire-alsa/noble,now 1.0.5-1 amd64 [instalado, automático]
  PipeWire ALSA plugin, for ALSA applications to output via PipeWire

pipewire-audio/noble,now 1.0.5-1 all [instalado, automático]
  recommended set of PipeWire packages for a standard audio desktop use

pipewire-audio-client-libraries/noble,now 1.0.5-1 all [instalado]
  transitional package for pipewire-alsa and pipewire-jack

pipewire-bin/noble,now 1.0.5-1 amd64 [instalado, automático]
  PipeWire multimedia server - programs

pipewire-doc/noble 1.0.5-1 all
  libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server - documentation

pipewire-jack/noble,now 1.0.5-1 amd64 [instalado, automático]
  PipeWire JACK plugin, for JACK applications to output via PipeWire

pipewire-libcamera/noble 1.0.5-1 all
  transitional package for libspa-0.2-libcamera

pipewire-module-xrdp/noble 0.2-2 all
  audio over xrdp for PipeWire based systems

pipewire-pulse/noble,now 1.0.5-1 amd64 [instalado, automático]
  PipeWire PulseAudio daemon

pipewire-tests/noble 1.0.5-1 amd64
  PipeWire multimedia server - tests and examples

pipewire-v4l2/noble 1.0.5-1 amd64
  PipeWire V4L2 plugin

What can I do, or... should get back to 22.04 LTS?

I have the same problem (Ideapad 5 Pro AMD 2024, Ubuntu 24.04 LTS) and I spent around a week and this is the solution.
The problem in Ubuntu 24.04 caused some applications to produce crackling and popping sounds, as if there was interference. This occurred with both speakers and headphones.
Since Ubuntu 24.04 uses Pipewire by default, I had to investigate there. The issue turned out to be that "old" applications (such as Steam games through Proton or even the brand-new Zoom) use PulseAudio instead of Pipewire. This generates so-called xruns: "dropouts" in the audio subsystem of Pipewire. You can easily see them by running the pw-top command in the terminal and checking if the number in the ERR column is increasing and for which application.
The situation is complicated by the fact that in 24.04, you cannot roll back to PulseAudio: ubuntu-desktop is now permanently dependent on Pipewire and can only be removed along with it. Therefore, Pipewire must be kept and configured.
I found a very cool guide on setting this up, but it turned out to be overkill for our case (the guide is here: https://forum.manjaro.…ling-in-pipewire/82442). According to the guide, if the ERRs are growing only for the driver, then the problem lies there. If the ERRs are growing for both the application and the driver, then it's an application issue, which can be fixed by increasing the latency for that application (and only for it). To do this, run the application with PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=126 COMMAND. You need to experiment with the number; the higher it is, the more the latency increases, which reduces audio processing problems but may affect sound quality. Through experimentation, I found that at 200, most problems disappeared, and at 300, all issues were resolved (this was when music was playing in the browser, a high-end 3D game was running through Proton, and a video conference was ongoing in Zoom).
To solidify the results, I adjusted two parameters in the Pipewire Pulse configuration file. Here's the step-by-step process:

Copy the folder /usr/share/pipewire to /etc/pipewire (so the settings apply to all users and applications).
Edit the file pipewire-pulse.conf in /etc/pipewire:
2.1. Find the pulse.min.quantum parameter and set it to 2048. Setting it to 1024 still caused failures under 100% load, but 2048 worked under any load.
2.2. Uncomment the next parameter: pulse.idle.timeout = 0.
Restart Pipewire to ensure everything works: systemctl --user restart wireplumber pipewire pipewire-pulse. If everything is okay, we've succeeded!

